# How to count adding elements?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, ajax

Using following js, I can get members. I need to count every time I get new member from the db. That I don't know how to do.

```
function intialize_memberDropDown(rowNumber, subrowNumber) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Member/GetAllMember/",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            debugger
            var countryHTMLString = "<option value ='0'>Select Member</option>";
            if (data.isSucess) {
                $.each(data.data, function (index, item) {
                    countryHTMLString += "<option value ='" + item.memberid + "'>" + item.membername + "</option>";
                });
            }
            $("#memberid" + rowNumber + subrowNumber + "").html(countryHTMLString)
        }, error: function (err) {
            debugger
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you count + 1 every time Ajax function calls, then you would count when it fails too. Also, the question says "I need to count every time I get new member from the db". Member iteration seems to be happening here:

```
$.each(data.data, function (index, item) {
countryHTMLString += "<option value ='" + item.memberid + "'>" + 
item.membername + "</option>";
});
```

So you would still declare the variable outside but count++ inside this iteration like this:

```
$.each(data.data, function (index, item) {
count++;
countryHTMLString += "<option value ='" + item.memberid + "'>" + item.membername + "</option>";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a variable outside the function and every time the ajax function calls, count +1 this variable, just like this :

```
var counter = 0;
function intialize_memberDropDown(rowNumber, subrowNumber) {
counter +=1;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Member/GetAllMember/",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            debugger
            var countryHTMLString = "<option value ='0'>Select Member</option>";
            if (data.isSucess) {
                $.each(data.data, function (index, item) {
                    countryHTMLString += "<option value ='" + item.memberid + "'>" + item.membername + "</option>";
                });
            }
            $("#memberid" + rowNumber + subrowNumber + "").html(countryHTMLString)
        }, error: function (err) {
            debugger
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By add this:

```
 var rowCount = $('#memberid').html(data).find('tr').length;


function intialize_memberDropDown(rowNumber, subrowNumber) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Member/GetAllMember/",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            debugger
            var countryHTMLString = "<option value ='0'>Select Member</option>";
            if (data.isSucess) {
                $.each(data.data, function (index, item) {
                    countryHTMLString += "<option value ='" + item.memberid + "'>" + item.membername + "</option>";
                });
            }
// tr is table row table html
 var rowCount = $('#memberid').html(data).find('tr').length;

            $("#memberid" + rowNumber + subrowNumber + "").html(countryHTMLString)
        }, error: function (err) {
            debugger
        }
    });
}
```